# Providing colorspace information in WinRT

Tags: c++-winrt

macOS programming allows the creation of colors(`NSColor`) with colorspace information via the [`createWithColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1533762-colorwithcolorspace) API which can then be queried via the [`colorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1526733-colorspace?language=objc) property. I don't find anything similar on the WinRT/C++ language projection. The only color space or profile-related API I came across was to query the current display's color profile via the [`GetColorProfileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.getcolorprofileasync?view=winrt-22621) API and the related [`ColorProfileChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.colorprofilechanged?view=winrt-22621) event but the `Color` struct doesn't appear to have any information pertaining to colorspace and only has the [RGBA values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.color?view=winrt-22621#fields). Is there some way to provide the colorspace information to the WinRT APIs similar to macOS or is there an alternate way to provide colorspace information while using colors?

Answer (score 0):

Currently UWP uses sRGB(a standard RGB (red, green, blue) color space), and related functions are all in the document [Color Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.color?view=winrt-22621#fields) as you have seen. UWP does not have API to operate on color space.

Comment: Is this something that's slated to change in WinUI3?

Comment: Currently [WinUI3 Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/color#color-api) also uses sRGB. You can submit a feature request on [microsoft-ui-xaml issues.](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues)